# Get token with Angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, token, moodle

I'm working on an Angularjs + Moodle + WebService APP

I have done a little Login page and  have a question.

I'm getting the Token of my user via `$.ajax` and I can see it in my chrome console.

The thing is, I want to save that token for using it in WS moodle fuctions and I'm usin `JSON.strungify` to get the token, but I have not successed.

I just get -> {readystate: 1} as an alert, instead get a token. but in my `console.info(response);` I got the token as show the next image :

[image: JS Response]

Thi is my code:

controller.js

```
var app = angular.module('mainApp', ['ngRoute', 'toaster', 'ngAnimate']);

app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'login.html'
    })
    .when('/dashboard', {
        resolve: {
            "check": function($location, $rootScope) {
                if(!$rootScope.loggedIn){
                    $location.path('/');
                } 
            }
        },  
        templateUrl: 'dashboard.html'   
    })
    .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
    });
});


app.controller('loginCtrl', 

function($scope, $location, $rootScope) {
    $scope.submit = function() {
        /*if($scope.username == 'admin' && $scope.password == 'admin') {
            $rootScope.loggedIn = true;
            $location.path('/dashboard');
        } else {
            alert('Wrong Stuff');
        }*/
        $rootScope.loggedIn = true;
        var username = $scope.username;
        var password = $scope.password;
        postCredentials(username, password/*, createSession*/);

    };

    function postCredentials(username, password, callback) {
    if (username!==null || password!==null) {


        var serverurl = 'https://comunidaddeaprendizaje.cl/ac-cap/login/token.php';

         var data = {
             username: username,
             password: password,
             service: 'moodle_mobile_app' // your webservice name
         }

         var response = $.ajax(
                            {   type: 'POST',
                                data: data,
                                url: serverurl,
                                dataType: 'JSON'
                            }
                         );

        console.info(response);
        dataString = JSON.stringify(response);
        alert(dataString);

             if (dataString.indexOf('error') > 0) {
               alert('Invalid user credentials, please try again');
             };

         } else {
            alert('Something Wrong');
         }
     }

}

);
```

login.html

```
div class="breadcrumbs" id="breadcrumbs">
    <ul class="breadcrumb">
        <li>
            <i class="ace-icon fa fa-home home-icon"></i>
            <a href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="active">Login</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="page-content">

<div class="row">
<div class="space-6"></div>
<div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1">
    <div id="login-box" class="login-box visible widget-box no-border">
        <div class="widget-body">
        <div class="widget-main">

        <h4>Login ACCAP</h4>

            <div ng-controller="loginCtrl">
            <form action="/"  class="form-horizontal" id="myLogin">
            <div class="form-group">
                UserName: 
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" ng-model="username" required focus><br>
                Password:  
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" ng-model="password"  required>
                </br>
                <button type="button" class="width-35 pull-right btn btn-sm btn-primary" ng-click="submit()">
                <div class="col-sm-7">
                <i class="ace-icon fa fa-key"></i>
                Login
                </button>
                </div>
            </div>
            </form>
            </div>

         </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Login APP</title>
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angularjs-toaster/1.1.0/toaster.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.7/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.3/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.0/angular-animate.min.js" ></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angularjs-toaster/1.1.0/toaster.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.js"></script>
    <script src="controller.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="mainApp">
    <div ng-view></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `response` variable is an object which contains a lot of information about the response. It is not the same as your response text.
Your second mistake is that your AJAX call is asynchronous, so you cannot obtain your response immediately after AJAX call. You need to wait for the response. Instead of

```
var response = $.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  data: data,
  url: serverurl,
  dataType: 'JSON'
});
console.info(response);
dataString = JSON.stringify(response);
alert(dataString);
if(dataString.indexOf('error') > 0) {
  alert('Invalid user credentials, please try again');
};
```

you should write

```
var response = $.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  data: data,
  url: serverurl,
  dataType: 'JSON',
  success: function(response) {
    console.info(response);
    dataString = JSON.stringify(response);
    alert(dataString);
    if(dataString.indexOf('error') > 0) {
      alert('Invalid user credentials, please try again');
    };
  }
});
```

Comment: I modified and I got `undefined`

Comment: @rfcabal. Because you put it in the wrong block of code. See my answer.

Comment: Now i can see the difference, just something more, after `if` i would like to do an else like: `else {$location.path('/dashboard');}`. I did it but i dont get redirected to /dashboard. Thank you